# Base mesh is rendered differently between viewport and final render with animation

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, armature, pose-mode

The "body" mesh stays in edit mode when it's supposed to be animation along the mesh, like in the viewport. Rigging is properly done and i don't know why the results are different.
[image: viewport]

Here is the viewport screen and the render screen.
[image]

Blend file is uploaded for more understanding.

[image]

Thank you

Paladin

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with Blender 2.79 and it works well. As you could see on the image below the possible problem could be the **inactive** *Armature Modifier* for the render circled in red.

[image]

On the other hand, I opened Your .blend file, load my custom HDRI map to light-up the scene, just render and everything is matching for me (even with that modifier turned off) as you could also check on the picture. Does this helps?

Sincerely, Jan